# Espresso test to verify that SwipeRefreshLayout is showing the refreshing indicator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, swiperefreshlayout

I would like to create an Espresso test which verifies that `SwipeRefreshLayout` is showing the refreshing indicator. How can I do this?

Comment: How have you called swipe-to-refresh in ui-test? I've tried swipeDown on SwipeRefreshLayout view and failed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no standard Espresso matcher for this, but you can create a custom one:

```
object SwipeRefreshLayoutMatchers {
    @JvmStatic
    fun isRefreshing(): Matcher<View> {
        return object : BoundedMatcher<View, SwipeRefreshLayout>(
            SwipeRefreshLayout::class.java) {

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("is refreshing")
            }

            override fun matchesSafely(view: SwipeRefreshLayout): Boolean {
                return view.isRefreshing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout)).check(matches(isRefreshing()))
```

Comment: How do you've called swipe-to-refresh in ui-test? I've tryed swipeDown on SwipeRefreshLayout view and failed